# why my CupertinoScrollbar not show in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I am using CupertinoScrollbar in flutter 2.0.1 like this:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: CupertinoScrollbar(
          child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
            16.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () => CommonUtils.launchUrl(item.link),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      item.title == "" ? "Comment" : item.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (item.domain != "")
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        navToChannelDetail();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        item.domain,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      )),
                ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.author,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: " ${String.fromCharCode(8226)} ",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.ago,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (item.content != "")
                Html(
                  data: item.content,
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                    ),
                  },
                  onLinkTap: (url) => CommonUtils.launchUrl(url),
                ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item.isFav == 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav", FavStatus.UNFAV),
                              ),
                            if (item.isFav != 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                                onPressed: () => touchFav("fav", FavStatus.FAV),
                              ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${item.favCount}",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item.isUpvote == 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                onPressed: () => touchUpvote("unupvote", UpvoteStatus.UNUPVOTE),
                              ),
                            if (item.isUpvote != 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                                onPressed: () => touchUpvote("upvote", UpvoteStatus.UPVOTE),
                              ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${item.upvoteCount}",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.share_2,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => handleShare(id: item.id, title: item.title, postUrl: item.link),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )));
```

but the UI not show scroll bar, where is going wrong and what should I do to fix it?

[image]

the error log shows:

```
======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      ScrollController.position (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:108:12)
#3      RawScrollbarState._maybeTriggerScrollbar.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart:862:27)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#5      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1090:9)
#6      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:998:5)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: try to add isAlwaysShown: true,

Comment: I added but still not shown, I wonder what's going wrong. @Anna

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: I have pasted the error log output into question @Anna

Answer (score 1):

add a controller to your CupertinoScrollbar

```
final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
```

Wrap your container with SingleChildScrollView and pass it _controller

Full code

```
return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: CupertinoScrollbar(
                controller: _controller, //Add this

           child : SingleChildScrollView( // wrap 
                controller: _controller, // add this

          child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
            16.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () => CommonUtils.launchUrl(item.link),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      item.title == "" ? "Comment" : item.title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (item.domain != "")
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        navToChannelDetail();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        item.domain,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      )),
                ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.author,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: " ${String.fromCharCode(8226)} ",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.ago,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (item.content != "")
                Html(
                  data: item.content,
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                    ),
                  },
                  onLinkTap: (url) => CommonUtils.launchUrl(url),
                ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item.isFav == 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav", FavStatus.UNFAV),
                              ),
                            if (item.isFav != 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                                onPressed: () => touchFav("fav", FavStatus.FAV),
                              ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${item.favCount}",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            if (item.isUpvote == 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                onPressed: () => touchUpvote("unupvote", UpvoteStatus.UNUPVOTE),
                              ),
                            if (item.isUpvote != 1)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                                onPressed: () => touchUpvote("upvote", UpvoteStatus.UPVOTE),
                              ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${item.upvoteCount}",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.share_2,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => handleShare(id: item.id, title: item.title, postUrl: item.link),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ))));
```

Comment: I follow your answer but the scroll bar still not show, the error disappeared now. @Anna

Comment: add isAlwaysShown: true to CupertinoScrollbar

Comment: there is no error output this time now, but sometimes the scroll not work. @Anna